# Animating shapes with text anchor in d3.js

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, d3.js

I am trying to transition a circle to a point on a curve and each circle has a text node within the circle as a child node and I am transitioning the cx,cy position of the circle and I would like the text to transition with it as well but it stays in the center of the svg.

```
mainLayerGroup.selectAll('.layerG')
  .append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'innerC')
  .attr('cx', 0)
  .attr('cy', 0)
  .attr('fill', 'black')
  .attr('r', layerRadius - 7)
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .delay(500)
  .ease('bounce')
  .attr('cx', function (d, i) {
    return (width / 2 - layerRadius - strokeWidth) * Math.cos((step * i) * Math.PI / 180);})
  .attr('cy', function (d, i) {
    return (width / 2 - layerRadius - strokeWidth) * Math.sin((step * i) * Math.PI / 180);});

mainLayerGroup.selectAll('.layerG')
  .append('text')
  .text(function(d){
    return d;
  })
  .attr("class", "layerTitle")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr('font-size', '36px')
  .attr('color', 'black');
```

[here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaunwallace/kuv3z/1/)

Any help is appreciated and if there are improvements to my current implementation then feedback is also appreciated :-) I am pretty new to d3.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to put everything to `g` elements and then translate those rather than all the elements individually. That is, your elements would be appended like this.

```
var subGroup = mainLayerGroup.selectAll('g')
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'layerG');

subGroup
  .append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'outerC')
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', strokeWidth)
  .attr('r', layerRadius)

// more elements appended...
```

Then you can translate everything like this:

```
subGroup.transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .delay(500)
  .ease('bounce')
  .attr('transform', function (d, i) {
    return "translate(" + ((width / 2 - layerRadius - strokeWidth) * Math.cos((step * i) * Math.PI / 180)) + "," + ((width / 2 - layerRadius - strokeWidth) * Math.sin((step * i) * Math.PI / 180)) + ")";
  });
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kuv3z/2/). I've also changed the styling so that you can see the text and it appears in the middle of the circles.

Comment: Thanks Lars, you seem to know d3 rather well :-)